# what kind of star would a planet need to sustain blue and pink flora and what effect would it have on ocean color?

Tags: science-fiction, flora, stars, ocean

The ecosystem on this planet, which I call Crilorix is thriving and I was hoping I can make the flora on the surface blue and pink? such as having blue leaves and pink bark on most trees and such, so what type of star/stars would I need? And would it change the ocean's color? Also unrelated question, would flying/levitating plants and algae be possible?

Comment: This may be an atmosphere thing, rather than sun color. For the water (the ocean) the color is determined by the water itself https://wordsinmocean.com/2015/10/21/if-water-is-clear-why-is-the-ocean-blue/ not the sun.. and the color of plants depends on the chemistry involved. I'm not an expert on the subject of biochemistry, but a color other than green may indicate less chlorofyl in the plant, so you would not have a CO2-oxigen cycle but something else ?

Comment: Earth has [blue-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria), [pink-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_algae) and [yellow-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_algae) photosynthetic organisms. It so happened that land plants evolved from [green algae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_algae); it was an evolutionary accident, it could have been any ot the other three groups. The point being that a star just like our Sun is good enough.

Comment: Yellow ok.. but wonder if something special is needed for blue plants ? That color is quite rare in Earth's nature.. I don't know of blue leafs.. there are some blue flowers..

Comment: Nice ref. Red, purple, green (mainly), and green-bluish chlorophyl.. No yellow. That is for the type of chlorophyl. Maybe chlorophyl always does the trick.. that topic gives a few nice tables ! alas no yellow or pink chlorophyl.. we see it in autumn, but not in the intact chlorofyl..

Comment: @Goodies: Phaeophytes are yellow-ish because of an auxiliary pigment. And there do definitely exist blue leaves, red leaves, purple leaves and so on, even among our mostly green land plants. For an easy example, the familiar [begonias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia) exhibit just about any imaginable leaf color. (And not only in cultivated varieties, but also in the wild; behold the spectacular [*Begonia pavonina*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Begonia+pavonina).)

Comment: @Goodies: Blue is rare among mammals, but that is only because most mammals have abysmal color vision and as a consequence there was no evolutionary incentive to develop attractive pigments. (Most mammals have poor color vision because our distant ancestors, back then when the dinosaurs ruled the world, were nocturnal.) Blue is not quite so rare among [birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_bluebird) [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_anole) [reptiles](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lacerta_viridis_-_male_01.JPG).

Comment: .. so nothing needs to be different, yellow and blue plants could be the prominent species, when evolution chooses that direction at some point ? Regardless of star type.. anything goes ?